# Issue in Batch Script EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a Batch script in which i have added `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and here goes the script

```
if %mnt% EQU 10 (
echo %mnt%
echo inside 10
set /A mnt=mnt-1
echo %mnt%
)
```

In the above script `set /A mnt=mnt-1` is not working at all. At last echo i.e `echo %mnt%` i am getting same value as `10` instead of `9`

What is wrong?

Comment: You are not using the variable correclty. `echo !mnt!`

Comment: @Squashman Thanks it Worked !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use exclamation marks instead of percent characters when using delayed expansion

`echo !mnt!`

You can also use:

`Set/A "mnt-=1"`